# Stray hat on the loose

Tags: bug, status-declined, chat, winter-bash-2013

I was in the chat a few minutes ago and I found a stray hat:

> [image]

I pointed it out and someone else was seeing it another way (a couple of lines further down):

> [image]

And when we refreshed the page, that hat was gone and I'm not really sure how to reproduce it (maybe it detected us seeing it and made its mind not to come close to the same room again). Were the hats programmed to walk around like that while they were out of their box?

It's not a big deal to me, it's just that I for one would be glad if I could get to catch a stray hat like that and add them to my collection, so if that's possible too, I want to know how =P

Comment: IT'S ALIVE AND TRYING TO STEAL OTHER HATS!!! LOOK AT IT SIDLING SUSPICIOUSLY ON THE SIDE OF THE PAGE THERE. RUN AND KEEP YOUR HATS SAFE! Why else would it jump around like that then disappear?

Comment: Fortunately, no case of missing hat(s) was reported. If anything, I'd want to get that one!

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards - Presumably I wouldn't be the first person to mention that "neb" is ben backwards?

Comment: Not at all @Martin! I've come up with various reasons, including a persecution complex, over time but to be honest I mainly do it to be difficult :-). It all depends on whether you want rotational symmetry or reflectional symmetry to mean backwards.

Comment: Yes. I suppose  `ben is uǝq rotated 180°` isn't quite as snappy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Sometimes, chat has a very windy day, and you have to hang onto your hats.

(This is a known bug that won't get fixed this time around due to time constraints. Plus, it's sort of fun to see them fly around. And no, you can't catch them.)

Comment: The kids should be leaning the other way, if the physics work like IRL. If the sum of forces acting on them is nonzero, things are going to get uncomfortable :-)

Comment: The kids have no hats! So, [meta-tag:status-declined]?

Comment: @Jan, I think they're being blown in that direction by the wind, not leaning into it for stability.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller in which case I think the camera has some pretty good shutter speed :-)

Comment: Aw I was really looking forward to catch them. I guess that bug won't be fixed. Thanks for clearing the doubts :)

Comment: [Looks like the hats are on the loose again this year](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5dYRd.png) :)